# Is there a way to interpolate scattered data onto a complex 3d grid?

Tags: python, interpolation

I am tracking particles in a flow field. I have position and velocity across the whole domain. This leaves me with a big data file with x, y, z co-ordinates and particle velocity. Is there a way to interpolate this scattered data onto the node points of existing domain, so that I will have a grid with particle data at its nodes?

Previously, I did the same on a planar grid (Just a rectangular grid) using np.meshgrid and scipy.interpolate.griddata.

```
def contours():
    size = 700 # Refining grid

    xi, yi = np.linspace(18.191, 61.851, size), np.linspace(0.25681, 17.721, size) # Define Domain

    xi, yi = np.meshgrid(xi, yi) # Forming a grid

    # xj, yj, uj are numpy arrays; Interpolation step
    zi = scipy.interpolate.griddata((xj, yj), uj/603.0, (xi, yi), method=method, fill_value=1.1)

    # Plotting
    plt.figure()
    plt.contour(xi ,yi, zi, np.linspace(0, 1.0, 10), linewidths=1.0, linestyles='dashed', cmap='jet')
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.xlabel('X(mm)')
    plt.ylabel('Y(mm)')
    plt.xlim(18.2, 61.9)
    plt.ylim(0.257, 17.7)

    return
```

The above code is working for the 2d problem. Is there a way to do the same for a 3d case? What to do if I have a pre-defined 3d grid and scattered data inside the domain?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Look at `scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator()`. It might be what you need.

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a try and update